# Fragment not able to restore saved instant state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have three activities: `ActivitySection` (Used with `FragmentSection` - a list), `ActivityChapter` (Used with `FragmentChapter` - a list) and `ActivityDetail` (Used with `FragmentDetail`).

`ActivityChapter` is a list is a sub list according to the selected item from `ActivitySection`. So when user moves from `ActivityChapter` to `ActivityDetail`, I store the selection section name so that when he presses back (on actionbar), I can restore the selected section name and populate the fragments content with the same sub list.

Here's my code to save the value:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(Konstant.KEY_SAVED_SECTION, mStrSelectedSection);
}
```

And here's my code to restore the value:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(Konstant.KEY_SAVED_SECTION))
            mStrSelectedSection = savedInstanceState.getString(Konstant.KEY_SAVED_SECTION);
}
```

When I moved from `ActivityChapter` to `ActivityDetail`, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called and `mStrSelectedSection` had the correct value. When I get back from `ActivityDetail`, `onCreate()` of `ActivityChapter` is called but `savedInstanceState` is `null`.

So, I am not able to populate the same sub list.

Can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using Fragments, why would you want to restore the selection in the Activity (you are writing "onCreate() of ActivityChapter is called but savedInstanceState is null")?
I'd assume if you put the code above into your fragment the selection would be restored.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. This code is within the Fragment only.